# Is there a way to not have Bitbucket ask for my password every time when doing remote Mercurial operations?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

With all other Mercurial repos that I push to, I can set my username and password in my hgrc (actually, Mercurial.ini since I'm using Windows) for doing operations at a particular domain, and Mercurial won't prompt me for auth info.  However, even with these settings in place, Bitbucket *always* asks for my password.

My settings are as follows:

```
[auth]
bitbucket.prefix = bitbucket.org
bitbucket.username = myusername
bitbucket.password = mypassword
```

As I said, these settings work for all other repos I push to.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Turns out the issue here was that I was using the URL for the repository displayed on my Bitbucket repository's page, which includes the username in front of the bitbucket domain name, so it ended up looking like `https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepo`.

Apparently, when  the username is provided in this way, it ignores what's in the `[auth]` section.  I just changed the URL in the hgrc for my local clone of the repo, and it picked up the `[auth]` section stuff just fine.

Apologies for not including this detail in the question.

Comment: For me, the problem was using user 'git' @bitbucket.org as per the help on their website. They could have been a bit clearer about that. +1 for saving me time.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using the ssh:// URLs for bitbucket or the https:// URLs?  Bitbucket offers both.  If it's ssh you need to use ssh-agent or similar (`[auth]` sections aren't used by ssh) to keep a key in memory or switch to the https: URLs.  You could also try adding `bitbucket.schemes = http https` just in case, though if you're using the https:// URLs the default value of `https` should be fine.  Also be aware that bitbucket usernames are case sensitive -- that got me for awhile.

If none of that's working for you try turning on debugging with `--debug` and see if there are any messages that help.