# How I can submit changes to the master repos in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have seen a bitbucket Repos which I have private access. I fork (or clone the repos and got the access to the code).

in my own copy I made changes. Later I delete my own copy (I thing I will publish it to master directory).

I thing I have submit the changes to my own directories. Now problem is how I can submit that changes to the main repos.

Now when I right click on git commit -> Master then It's not show me any files. I have seen that the files in main repos are same as old and not have any changes I have done.

now someone help me then how I can commit the changes to the main repos of someone else. the repos of mine I have deleted on server so I have no idea how the main repos take my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your local clone refers to your BitBucket fork (that you just deleted), you can change your remote address named 'origin' to point it back to your main BitBucket repo.

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myrepo.git
# or (https address)
git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepo
```

(see also, for https address, [Is there a way to not have Bitbucket ask for my password every time when doing remote Mercurial operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933693/is-there-a-way-to-not-have-bitbucket-ask-for-my-password-every-time-when-doing-r) )

See for more [Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git)

You can then push to origin, meaning this time your first private BitBucket repo.

---

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1814971/user1814971) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834106/how-i-can-submit-changes-to-the-master-repos-in-bitbucket/13834175#comment19042423_13834175):

> I check all setting again and found that I have used the location which is relate to main repos.
>
> I have tried it `Git > sync > push` all changes and it's work fine

Comment: I check all setting again and found that I have used the location which is relate to main repos. I have tried it Git > sync > push all changes and it's work fine.

Comment: @user1814971 Excellent. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.